# How do I use a transient property with overridden NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I'm currently using [MSCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout). The original coredata model is Event, which described a transient property "day"

```
//MSEvent.h
@interface MSEvent : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *start;
    - (NSDate *)day; // Derived attribute to make it easy to sort events into days by equality
@end


//MSEvent.m
- (NSDate *)day
{
    return [self.start beginningOfDay];
}
```

And the original code uses RestKit, while separating section by the transient property "day".

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
    managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext 
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"day" 
    cacheName:nil];
```

This works just fine.

---

Here's my problem: Instead of RestKit, I use my own ManagedObjectContext

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"day" 
    cacheName:nil];
```

And I would update the event somewhere

```
event = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[event setValue:eventData[@"startDate"] forKey:@"start"];
[managedObjectContext save:nil]; // here the problem occurs
```

I got error message in the last line:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  [<NSManagedObject 0x9386a50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Event is not key value coding-compliant for the key "day".
```

Adding a "day" property in the Core Data model would solve the problem.

---

So my question is: I think a transient property of a NSManagedObject can provide extra accessors without persisting an actual value, just like a category. So why I am getting this error when I try to save the managed object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself: I forgot to add Class in the Data Model Inspector.